# Why does freeing a string in a trie result in a malloc error?

Tags: c, malloc, trie

I need help understanding a debug message that I got from `malloc`.  I wrote a function that deletes a specified string from a trie by recursively traversing that string on the trie and freeing everything that isn't used by another string.  This involves going down to the very last node and freeing it, then going back up the stack and checking each level to see if that level is also unused by other strings, and if so, freeing them.  Once it gets to the first one that is used by something else, it stops.

The function seems to work fine when I only remove one string, but when I remove a second string, I start having problems.  Here's the entire code of my program so far (note that some of the lines are there for testing/debugging purposes and are not integral to the program):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct node {
    char chr;
    bool end;
    struct node *children[128];
};

void add( struct node *, char * );
void del( struct node *, char * );
bool isMember( struct node *, char * );

bool recursiveDel( struct node *, char * );
// del is really just a dummy function that calls recursiveDel.

int main( int argc, char **argv ){
    struct node *trie = (struct node *) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ ){
        add( trie, argv[i] );
    }
    del( trie, argv[1] );
    del( trie, argv[2] );
    for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ ){
        printf( "%d\n", isMember( trie, argv[i] ) );
    }
    return 0;
}

void add( struct node *trie, char *str ){
    int i = 0;
    while( str[i] ){
        // Check/goto next node
        // If NULL, create next node
        if( trie->children[str[i]] == NULL )
            trie->children[str[i]] = (struct node *) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        trie = trie->children[str[i++]];
    }
    trie->end = true;
}

void del( struct node *trie, char *str ){
    if( isMember( trie, str ) ){
        recursiveDel( trie, str );
    }
}

bool isMember( struct node *trie, char *str ){
    int i = 0;
    struct node *cur = trie;
    while( str[i] ){
        if( trie->children[str[i]] == NULL ) return false;
        else trie = trie->children[str[i++]];
    }
    return trie->end;
}

// Features of this function:
// When it gets to the leaf, it deletes that node and then starts going back up the call stack
// Each call passes a Boolean value back up the call stack.
// This boolean value indicates whether or not the node was deleted.
// If the value returned from the lower node is true, then that means check the next node up to see if it should be deleted.
// If false do nothing, because there are other strings using this node.
bool recursiveDel( struct node *trie, char *str ){
    printf( "%p, %d, %s\n", trie, trie->end, str );
    if( trie->end ){
        free( trie );
        return true;
    }
    bool deleted = recursiveDel( trie->children[str[0]], str+1 );
    if( deleted ){
        int used = 0;
        // Loop checks to see if the node
        // is used by any other strings.
        for( int i = 0; i < 128; i++ ){
            if( trie->children[i] ){
                used++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( used <= 1 ){
            free( trie );
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem appears to occur in this block, where I attempted to free the terminating node for the string:

```
    if( trie->end ){
        free( trie );
        return true;
    }
```

I get a message saying that the node can't be freed because it doesn't exist...

```
bash-3.2$ ./trie hello world
0x7fd370802000, 0, hello
0x7fd370800600, 0, ello
0x7fd370802600, 0, llo
0x7fd370802c00, 0, lo
0x7fd370803200, 0, o
0x7fd370803800, 1,
0x7fd370802000, 0, world
0x7fd370803e00, 0, orld
0x7fd370804400, 0, rld
0x7fd370804a00, 0, ld
0x7fd370805000, 0, d
0x7fd370805600, 1,
trie(43216,0x7fff7818e000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd370802000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
bash-3.2$
```

It appears to be the case that when I try to remove the second string, it goes to the last node as expected, but then rather than going back up the stack, it keeps going and tries to free the next node after that, which obviously it can't do because this is a leaf node.

It seems like it might be undefined behavior, but at the same time, the program fails in a very predictable way - the first string removal is invariably successful while the second string removal is invariably unsuccessful.  I can't make heads or tails of this.

Also, the address given by `malloc` when it failed seems a little off.  The last few addresses all differ by `0x600`, but this address differs from the last one by `0xa00`.  I understand that heap memory allocation is unpredictable, but I just thought I'd point that out.

More strange than that is the fact that the address given by `malloc` is different from the last printed address, despite the fact that the failed `free` operation immediately follows the last `printf`.  This almost seems to indicate that the compiler is inserting a pointer advancing operation between the `printf` line and the `if( trie->end ) free( trie )` part.  Common sense indicates that this is ridiculous, but I don't know of any other explanation.

Comment: See [mcve] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: did you read your error message ?

Comment: `malloc( sizeof( struct node ) )` doesn't zero your pointers. So your test against `NULL` doesn't work and you're freeing unallocated memory. Use `calloc` instead

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  Amongst other things, several of the array indexes are 'char' rather than some numeric value.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11` )   The parameters are different for visual studio, etc

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, 1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 5):

Relevant portion of your code:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv ){
    struct node *trie = (struct node *) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ ){
        add( trie, argv[i] );
    }
    …
}

void add( struct node *trie, char *str ){
    int i = 0;
    while( str[i] ){
        if( trie->children[str[i]] == NULL )
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You're allocating a `struct node`, then accessing its `.children[...]` pointer without initializing it. Undefined behavior.

You need to initialize your `node`s after allocating them.

Answer (score 4):

Your `add` function is incorrect here:

```
trie->children[str[i]] = (struct node *) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
```

You use `malloc()` that does not initialize the memory block it returns. Same problem in `main()`. Indeed it would make sense to have 2 different structure types for the trie and its nodes.

You should use `calloc()` or `memset()` to initialize the contents to all bits zero, which is good enough for most current architectures to initialize all the `children` pointers to `NULL`.

Note also that you have undefined behavior if any of the characters are outside the range `0`..`127`. You should give the `children` array 256 entries and cast the `char` as `unsigned char` before using it an index.

Another problem: in `recursiveDel` you should just clear `trie->end` and only free the node if all its `children` pointers are `NULL` too. Same problem for intermediary nodes: you must check that `trie->end` is false too before freeing the node.

Looking closer to the `recursiveDel` function, it is broken in multiple ways. Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct node {
    char chr;
    bool end;
    struct node *children[256];
};

void add(struct node *trie, const char *str);
void del(struct node *trie, const char *str);
bool isMember(struct node *trie, const char *str);

bool recursiveDel(struct node *trie, const char *str);
// del is really just a dummy function that calls recursiveDel.

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct node *trie = calloc(sizeof(struct node), 1);
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        add(trie, argv[i]);
    }
    if (argc > 1)
        del(trie, argv[1]);
    if (argc > 2)
        del(trie, argv[2]);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", isMember(trie, argv[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}

void add(struct node *trie, const char *str) {
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        // Check/goto next node
        // If NULL, create next node
        if (trie->children[(unsigned char)str[i]] == NULL)
            trie->children[(unsigned char)str[i]] = calloc(sizeof(struct node), 1);
        trie = trie->children[(unsigned char)str[i]];
    }
    trie->end = true;
}

void del(struct node *trie, const char *str) {
    if (isMember(trie, str)) {
        recursiveDel(trie, str);
    }
}

bool isMember(struct node *trie, const char *str) {
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (trie->children[(unsigned char)str[i]] == NULL)
            return false;
        else
            trie = trie->children[(unsigned char)str[i]];
    }
    return trie->end;
}

// Features of this function:
// When it gets to the leaf, it resets the end flag
// and check if the node can be removed and returns true if so.
// Each call passes a Boolean value back up the call stack.
// This boolean value indicates whether or not the node can be deleted.
// If so, the caller frees it and clears the pointer
// If false do nothing, because there are other strings using this node.
bool recursiveDel(struct node *trie, const char *str) {
    //printf("%p, %d, %s\n", (void *)trie, trie->end, str);
    if (*str) {
        if (!recursiveDel(trie->children[(unsigned char)str[0]], str + 1))
            return false;
        free(trie->children[(unsigned char)str[0]]);
        trie->children[(unsigned char)str[0]] = NULL;
    } else {
        trie->end = false;
    }
    if (trie->end)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (trie->children[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: "*[...] all bits zero, which is good enough to initialize all the `children` pointers to `NULL`.*" This is not required by the C standard. It's true on all common platforms, though.

Comment: I will try that.  Thanks.

Comment: @melpomene: that's what I implied by *good enough*, but I amended the answer to clarify this point. I wish the C Standard would give up on keeping these options open and focus on real life hardware to simplify everybody's life.

Comment: I changed `malloc` to `calloc` and I'm still getting the same error message.  I don't think that was the problem.

Comment: Why not run your program in a debugger such as `gdb` or `lldb` and set a breakpoint on `malloc_error_break`?